# How to crop detected object given the edge points in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have the 2D coordinates of the edge points `[x,y]` of the objects in gery image (img). Where `x` and `y` are `nx1` vectors. The objects have irregular shapes.

My question is how can we crop (or extract the image of the object from the original image (img) using matlab.

The following sample of my code:

```
Input_Grey = rgb2gray(Input_RGB);
[B,L] = bwboundaries(CC); % where CC is the binary image with the edges of the objects.

boundary = B{1}; % the edge points of the first object.

x = boundary(:, 2);

y = boundary(:, 1);
```

Comment: `Input_Grey(min(y):max(y),min(x):max(x))`

Comment: @user2999345 this crop a rectangular shape; but the objects I have are irregular.

Comment: so what do you mean by "crop"? you can try `poly2mask(x,y,size(Input_Grey,1),size(Input_Grey,2))`